# Understanding the arrow operator -> in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand the correct use of the -> operator in C. I think I have the understanding, but need to have that validated. so...

if i have an 32 bit data structure (eg. MyStruct) to store some status data (1s or 0s) which is pointed to by pnt. there are 3 members of that data structure ('first', 'second' both 8 bit, and 'third' 16-bit)

If I have

```
pnt -> second ^= (1<<2)
```

this can be written as

```
pnt -> second = pnt -> second ^ (1<<2)
```

then this is saying that;
get the value of 'second' from the structure MyStruct that is being pointed to by pnt. XOR that value with a bit that has been shifted left (i.e. 00000100). Whatever the result, put that back into MyStruct at the member 'second'

yes?

Thanks.

Comment: In one place, you write `(1<<3)`, in another place you write `(1<<2)`. Is this intended? Or is this a typo? If it is a typo, please [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: The question seems to be about `^=` , not `->`

Comment: Your understanding appears correct to me.

Comment: Although it has no effect, the spaces around the `->` is contrary to the way most C code is written... Try to get used to `ptr->member` as that is what you find in the big, wide world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pnt->second` is a shorthand for `(*pnt).second` which means "take the struct pointed to by `pnt` and from that struct, get the element `second`".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [compound assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment)

```
A ^= B;
```

has the same effect as

```
A = A ^ B;
```

---

Note that `pnt -> second ^= (1<<3)` can **not** be written `pnt -> second = pnt -> second ^ (1<<2)` though. `1<<3` is not the same as `1<<2`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a typo. should have been (1<<2) in both cases

Answer (score 0):

As for the assignment part of your question, the statements A=A XOR B is identical to A XOR= B, as with many other operators.

just make sure to change the (1<<2)(1<<3) difference between the lines.

As for the header of your question regarding the arrow(->) symbol:
Given a struct A, you can reference a field (second) within the struct by two ways -

1. A.second
2. (&A)->second - that is, if you have a **pointer** to A, call it B (*B=A) -
   so referencing will be done thus: B->second.

hope that clarifies your question.